# curl --cert worl fine, but php curl CURLOPT_CAPATH not work

Tags: php, curl, openssl, certificate

I try yo make request for https url. I do it via cmd and curl like:

```
curl --cert cert.pem https://my_test.com
```

and it work fine. then i try do it with php and can't connect to url. I reale try many solutions

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen("D://curl_debug.txt", "w+"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CA\\"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cert.pem");
```

in curl_debug.txt I get: **uccessfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: D:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: D:\xampp\htdocs\CA\
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream**

may be someone have any idea, what is problem? Thanks!